# Python: get type object from its name?

Tags: python, types

Is there a way to get a type object, given the name of that type? 
So, for example:

```
   get_type('str') -> str
```

I am building a `dict` mapping various cases to a class which should be instantiated to handle them. It seems overkill to import everything and risk circular imports. So I thought I could specify them with strings, and look up the type at point of use. But how do I look up the type?

It seems unlikely that this hasn't been asked before, but I've searched and not found it.

Comment: Import, and worry about resolving circular imports once you actually encounter a problem.

Comment: This was suggested by @AndrejKesely, but I can't now find it:

    >>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    >>> globals()['BeautifulSoup']
    <class 'bs4.BeautifulSoup'>

It seems to work beautifully for non-builtins.

Comment: The point of storing a string was to have a dict mapping some string to `'BeautifulSoup'`, allowing the actual import to be deferred.

Comment: @chepner yes, I know. So?

Comment: Your comment doesn't defer the import.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can get the builtin types by checking attribute on the `builtins` module using `getattr`:

```
In [665]: import builtins 
In [666]: def get_type(type_name): 
     ...:     try: 
     ...:         return getattr(builtins, type_name) 
     ...:     except AttributeError: 
     ...:         return None 
     ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                   

In [667]: get_type('str')                                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[667]: str

In [668]: get_type('list')                                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[668]: list

In [669]: get_type('dict')                                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[669]: dict
```

---

FWIW, you can replace the `AttributeError` catching with passing the third parameter to `getattr` which acts as a default when attribute is missing (thanks @Error - Syntactical Remorse for the reminder):

```
def get_type(type_name):
    return getattr(builtins, type_name, None)
```

---

For handling custom types, you can peek into the `globals` dict:

```
In [670]: def get_type(type_name): 
     ...:     try: 
     ...:         return getattr(builtins, type_name) 
     ...:     except AttributeError: 
     ...:         try: 
     ...:             obj = globals()[type_name] 
     ...:         except KeyError: 
     ...:             return None 
     ...:         return repr(obj) if isinstance(obj, type) else None 
     ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                          

In [671]: class B: 
     ...:     pass 
     ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                   

In [672]: get_type('B')                                                                                                                                                                                     
Out[672]: "<class '__main__.B'>"

In [673]: get_type('C') is None
Out[673]: True
```

Comment: You can also skip the import by just using `__builtins__` :)

Comment: @heemayl Could it be done for custom types? for example if I define `class A` so `get_type('A')` should return `<class A>`

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse They are the same object. Try `__builtins__ is builtins`. Using dunder module doesn't seem pretty to my eyes.

Comment: @heemayl exactly, just one doesn't require you to use `import builtins`, but gotcha.

Comment: @AndrejKesely Use the `try/except` from above and in the `except` do this: `getattr(sys.modules[__name__], type_name, None)`, that will catch your own class instances.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse Actually you can just check `globals`, edited.

Comment: @AndrejKesely Check my edits.